# Activation Record Length

Tags: c, activation-record

I get 6,4,3 for the first 3 questions respectively, but I don't know how to figure out the last one. However, the solution manual indicated 7,5,4,18 as the answers.

```
int sum(int x[], int N) {
  int k = 0;
  int s = 0;
  while (k < N) {
    s = s + x[k];
    k = k + 1;
  }
  return s; // the activation record for sum will be ____________ locations
}

int fred(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;  // (2) the activation record for fred will be ____________ locations
}

void barney(int x) {
  x = fred(x, x);//(2) the activation record for barney will be ____________ locations
}

void main(void) {
  int a[4];
  int x = sum(a, 4);
  barney(x); 
} // (3) the stack must have at least _____________ locations to run this program
```

Comment: if this is a homework problem (which is obvious taking your other question into account), at least have the decency to say so with a tag

Comment: and what is your answer/guess?

Comment: what is the question in first place?

Comment: I get 6,4,3 for the first 3 questions respectively, but idk how to figure out the last one..

Comment: If this is a program your instructor gave you, you should consider changing the class you're in, or changing the instructor.

Comment: Without knowing a great deal more of the "rules" being used, it's an impossible question to answer. What is a "location", and how many "locations" are used by each int, pointer, return address, and so on? How many (if any) parameters of what types can/will be passed in registers? Will the compiler do optimizing like inlining and/or dead-code elimination? With dead-code elimination, the answer could well be zero (i.e. it's *all* dead code).

Comment: @Jerry Would a sample solution help? The solutions are 7, 5, 4, and 18 respectively...

Comment: How big is an int? How big is a pointer? Where does the return value go?

Comment: And what architecture? On ARM, for instance, the first 4 arguments are passed via registers r0–r3 instead of the stack, so the stack frame will surely be different.

Comment: my oh my, its terrible to see what goes on in CS classes. On many processors u could imagine sum() using no stack, just registers. 
On others quite a lot of stack. But mainly - who cares if the answer is 4,5 or 6. And for sure any decent compiler will use no stack for fred() or barney()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont know what is the convention of your book, but I assume, there is always a place for return address, address of return value and intermediate results

a)return address, address of return result, x, N, k, s, intermediate result for s + x[k] = total 7

b)ret. addr, addr of ret result, a, b, int. res. a+b = total 5

c)ret. addr, addr of ret result, x, space for return result of fred = total 4

d)last one is not asking the activation record max required stack size at any given point. It calls sum, It calls barney and barney calls fred that is 7+5+4 = 16. And 16 + a + x = total 18 locations to run this program.

Note that, this calculations are based on my wild guess about your books convention.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the one location you are missing in each of the first three assignments is the saved frame pointer, i.e. the pointer to the current stack location **before** local variables are allocated. The frame pointer needs to be restored on exit of the function so that the return address is indeed at the top of stack before the function returns.

The solution to the last task is just the maximum of the sums of the allocation record lengths *arl* of nested calls. So, in this example

```
arl(program) = max(arl(main)+arl(sum), arl(main)+arl(barney)+arl(fred))
```

sum and barney are not called at the same time, so they don't need to be added, as the allocation record for sum is already freed when the one for barney is allocated.

As arl(main) is 7 (return address, saved frame pointer, array of 4 ints, int), the second sum gives the bigger value of 16. However, this is two less than the indicated answer.Maybe your book gives you an indication what the other two locations are supposed to be.